# regular expression for exact word with additional characters only

Tags: regex

I need to exclude a few SharePoint sites from crawling. I would like to use a regular expression to do that.

How should the regular expression be setup?

Note: I have a crawl rule to exclude `://mytestapps.test.com/projects/docs/`, but need to add another crawl rule to include only `://mytestapps.test.com/projects/docs/*` sites.

For example: only `/docssite1/` or `/docssite2/`, not `/docs/`.

Comment: To clarify, you want ://mytestapps.test.com/projects/docsite1/* or ://mytestapps.test.com/projects/docsite2/*, and so on, BUT, not ://mytestapps.test.com/projects/docs/ -- correct?

Comment: I am also a bit confused on this.  My answer is based on selecting anything with `/docs/` given that there is an option like "Exclude these sites from crawl".  I'm not as familiar with Central Admin so not sure it that's how it's set up or not.

Answer (score 2):

A regular expression you could use to pick up sites that have `/docs/` in them would be `/^.+/docs/.*/g`

If you'd like to test what would and wouldn't get caught by this you can test it on a site like http://www.regexr.com/.  I like this site in particular because of how easy it is to test with any text as well as having the 'cheatsheet' on the side.

EDIT:

Based on your update try this out `/:\/\/mytestapps.test.com\/projects(?!\/docs\/).*/g`.  This matches any that are NOT `/docs/`.  However this will only work if the address all starts the same (`://mytestapps.test.com/projects`).

Comment: My favorite is https://regex101.com

Comment: Updated answer based on new info.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the confusion. Yes @Balowknee.

I want
://mytestapps.test.com/projects/docsite1/* or ://mytestapps.test.com/projects/docsite2/*, and so on, BUT, not ://mytestapps.test.com/projects/docs/

Answer (score 0):

If you need a regex to find

`[some characters]/docs[plus some more characters here]/[plus some more characters here]`

you just need to add a little to what Jordan posted:

`/^.+\/docs\w+\/.*/g`